# Php utf8 text with accents from mysql db getting wrong with regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have some data in my MySQL (all utf8) database with accents.
Like "7h à 18H" (in french, which means 7am to 6pm).
In my php script, i set the mysql connection encoding to utf8 and when i gather the text up there "7H à 18H", the accent displays correctly in the CLI (because i'm running scripts in CLI).

Then after i try to parse the expression with

```
preg_match("#[0-9]+H [Àà] [0-9]+H#i", $text);
```

but the regex didn't match.
I didn't understand why then i tried this expression

```
preg_match("#[0-9]+H [Àà]#i",$text,$matches)
```

It have worked but the matches were :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "7H �"
}
```

With a wrong accent ! So that's why the space after the accent isn't interpreted as a space but as the continuity of the wrong accent before maybe ?

I'm getting mad with. Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Finally, i found it.

I have to add the option "u" to preg_match like

```
preg_match("#[0-9]+H [Àà] [0-9]+#iu",$text,$matches)
```

To tell preg_match that it is and encoded utf8 string. I don't know why it is not done by default. Maybe someone has an answer.

Comment: `I don't know why it is not done by default.` because you haven't [**R**ead **T**he **F**antastic **M**anual.](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) ;)

Comment: [The answer is buried here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) -- Yuck.  And it seems that adding `(*UTF8)` to the beginning of the pattern string works.